# How to bind dropdownlist to a grid view in asp.net??? Here dropdownlist is not inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind gridview to a dropdownlist meaning when i change my dropdownlist value data must be accordingly displayed in asp.net.But whenever i build the application following errror occurs:

**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ClassName'.**

How can i solve this error?? I have configured two different tables of same database as a source for  gridview and dropdownlist.When i test query in gridview in case of data configuration, data comes in form of rows and columns but when i build application above error occurs. My aspx code is below:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Resultgridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="StudentID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" 
                        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StudentID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                        SortExpression="Section" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" 
                        SortExpression="StudentName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RollNo" HeaderText="RollNo" 
                        SortExpression="RollNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                        SortExpression="Address" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="GuardianName" HeaderText="GuardianName" 
                        SortExpression="GuardianName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="GuardianPhone" HeaderText="GuardianPhone" 
                        SortExpression="GuardianPhone" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My cs code looks like this

```
  protected void ClassDropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Resultgridview.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    Resultgridview.DataBind();

    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=dbbilling;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select StudentName from students where Class='" + ClassDropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con);
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
}
```

What must i add and uncomment in cs file??

Comment: Please include the combobox markup in the post....  is the commented code where the error occurs?  Or is the error occurring when bound to the grid?  Also, is SqlDataSource1 a data sourc econtrol?